# Excel 2010 Conditional Formatting Cell color based on a group of text cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Hi I need help with changing the color of a cell based on the Text values in the cells below it.  So say B1 is the cell i want to change.   B2-B7 has text values 'Yes', 'No', 'In Progress'  I want to set this up so if 4 out of 6 has 'No' B1 changes to a red color and vice versa if 'Yes' It changes to green.  Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think to do this would be combining a formula with conditional formatting. So, paste the following formula in B1:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:B7,"No")=4,"red",IF(COUNTIF(B2:B7,"Yes")=4,"green",""))
```

That formula will enter "red" in cell B1 if there are 4 cells in range B2:B7 which are "No". Similarly, if 4 cells in the range say "Yes", then the cell will be populated with "green".

You can then apply two simple conditional formatting rules on cell B1 where if the cell contains "red", it will set the cell fill color and the text color to red. The same for green.

[image]

Comment: If you are going to have two rules anyways why not just have the two formulas in the Conditional Formatting, then there is no need to put the formula in the cells and allows the OP to put a title or any other verbiage in the cell?